# abbreviation following command in Vim

Tags: vim

I have following abbreviation in Vim.

```
iabbr forr  for(int i=0; i<len; i++)
```

It works fine, but I want the cursor move to left after the iabbr.

I have tried following so far:

```
iabbr forr for(int i=0; i<len; i++) :10h

10h - move the cursor to left 10 characters from current position
```

It does't work, it only prints all the text including :10h

Question:

**how do I execute command after abbreviation?
I went through the :help iabbr and did not find any info how to execute command.**

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure that is really possible actually.

A pretty crappy workaround would be:

```
iabbr forr  for(int i=0; i<len; i++) <Esc>hhhhhhhhhh
```

But that is terrible.

Instead you could be interested in plugins like
[Vim-snippets](https://github.com/honza/vim-snippets) and
[Ultisnips](https://github.com/SirVer/ultisnips) or
[neosnippets](https://github.com/Shougo/neosnippet.vim): They allow to enter
preformated pieces of code with some part ready to be changed. I think it is
what you need.

Answer (score 2):

You can use expression mappings/abbreviations for this:

```
:iabbr <expr> forr  'for(int i=0; i<len; i++) '."\<esc>".repeat('h',10)
```

Read the help at :h map-expression for the details about this.

Alternatively, you could set a mark and jump to it:

```
:iabbr forr  for(int i=0; i<<C-O>malen; i++) <C-O>`a
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is simply

```
iabbr forr  for(int i=0; i<len; i++)<ESC>10hi
```

`<ESC>` sets in normal mode, the last `i` sets back in insertion mode.